# rxjs-websockets - how to encapsulate as angular 6/7 service

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

https://github.com/ohjames/rxjs-websockets seems to do a wonderful job, but i am struggling to make it as an angular 6 service global do the app. 
Does anyone know how to encapsulate the library as a service?

Thanks
Pucci

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this in another way. 
As i am using MQTT over websockets and not websockets itself, the ngx-mqtt module already created observables for subscribing into channels. 
The question is going to stay online because this topic mix observables and promises and I know more people will struggle on this.